# Problem when appending a variable with a numbering scheme to a list

Tags: python, string, list

```
a1 = 0
a2 = 1

x = [] #here I have declared an empty list
for i in range(2):
    x.append('a'+str(i+1)) #to append the variable with a numbering scheme
print (x)
```

This is a sample python code. A similar situation that I am facing in a programming task .

Here the output is `['a1','a2']` instead I need the output as `[0,1]`. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: `x.append(i)`.... You append `'a{i +1}'`....

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse in this example, `i` is correct but he wants to use the values of `a1` and `a2`. Your comment won't work in more elaborate examples

Comment: The marked duplicate should be considered than, and you are most likely doing something wrong. You probably want to use a `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **MUST** use variables already existing in your scope, you can use `locals()` to get all local variables as a dict

```py
a1 = 0
a2 = 1

x = [] #here I have declared an empty list
for i in range(2):
    x.append(locals()['a'+str(i+1)]) #to append the variable with a numbering scheme
print (x)
```

Comment: Good for indicating that this should be avoided at all costs

Comment: Even then it would probably be better (less bad?) to use `locals` or `globals` instead of `eval`. (Oh, you just did while I typed this...)

Comment: Hi , 
Thankyou so much for the help . I dont have much experience in programming. Also the solution that you gave me works like I expected. I would like to know what consequences will I have in this kind of programming since you have mentioned "very bad programming practice"

Comment: eval/exec are generally abused to do a task where they aren't needed, very slow, opens up security issues,....

Comment: @AadithyaSathya my first version was using `eval`, which is not recommended  because it executes code (it interprents the parameter as python code), which can lead to severe security issues and bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary for this:

```
d = {'a1': 0, 'a2':1}
x = [] #here I have declared an empty list
for i in range(2):
    x.append(d['a'+str(i+1)]) #to append the variable with a numbering scheme
print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vars = {
    'a1': 0,
    'a2': 1,
}

x = []

for var in vars.keys():
    x.append(vars[var])

print(x)
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer